# Django - How to include a map in a modal form and save coordinates to database when user selects point on map?

Tags: django, database, model, maps, coordinates

I am working on a project and a student of Web Development.

I am making an application in Django. When a user creates a new trip with a form I've made, I want to add a map to that form so that users only have to click a point on a map in order to get coordinates to save to the database for that trip.

I want to save coordinates for every new trip so that I can render a map on each user's profile page that shows them markers of every trip they've taken that is in the database.

Please help!

Thank you

**Here's some code:**

models.py

```
class Trip (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='trips') 
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    trail =  models.CharField(max_length=300)
    permit = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    location = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=400)
    lat = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    lng = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add =True)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.trail

def total_days(self):
    return (self.end_date - self.start_date).days
```

forms.py

```
class CreateTrip(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(     
            attrs={'type': 'date'} 
        )
    )     
    end_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(     
            attrs={'type': 'date'} 
        )
    )


    class Meta():
        model = models.Trip
        fields = ('trail','location', 'permit', 'completed', 'start_date', 'end_date')
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like to me you have a couple of many-to-one relationships you want to store in your database. My answer is based on this documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

You have Users that can go on many trips.

So you'd have a model called Trip that would look something like:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ... whatever else ...
```

And your trips have points so you might want a model like this:

```
class Point(models.Model):
    lat = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    lng = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    order = models.IntegerField() # ordering for the points.
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)
    ... whatever else ...
```